# PopupMenu crash on show for Android 10 11

Tags: android, crash, popupmenu

The following code crashes for Android 10,11 works fine for 7,8:

```
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            ...
            return true;
        }
    });
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_xxxx, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
```

This is the crash log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xxx.yyy, PID: 6024
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in android:layout/popup_menu_item_layout: Binary XML file line #17 in android:layout/popup_menu_item_layout: Error inflating class com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuItemView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in android:layout/popup_menu_item_layout: Error inflating class com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuItemView
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Field.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.ReflectionUtils.getValue(ReflectionUtils.java:29)
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.createCustomViewInternal(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:203)
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.access$000(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:20)
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater$PrivateWrapperFactory2.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:302)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:237)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1067)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:657)
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuAdapter.getView(MenuAdapter.java:82)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopup.measureIndividualMenuWidth(MenuPopup.java:158)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.tryShow(StandardMenuPopup.java:173)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.show(StandardMenuPopup.java:207)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.showPopup(MenuPopupHelper.java:283)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:178)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.show(MenuPopupHelper.java:142)
        at android.widget.PopupMenu.show(PopupMenu.java:230)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using an old library https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy
Once updated , it works fine.

Comment: Glad you found that while I was writing my answer :) In terms of completeness I posted mine too with another possible issue and it's solution. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

Update your libraries in the gradle and refresh your imports.

**Solution 2:**

Sometimes there are issues with the behaviour of the menu.

For that, remove `collapseActionView` or change it to `always` from this
`app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"` to `app:showAsAction="always"`